# Are there any portable versions of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, portable-gis

I am looking for a portable version of QGIS. 
Do you know if there are any portable version of QGIS?

Comment: http://archaeogeek.com/blog/2015/08/20/portable-gis-5-dot-2/ says QGIS 2.8.

Comment: There is also OSGeoLive, at the time of writing it's quite outdated at version 2.4, but for future reference: http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updating this answer with links to PortableGIS 5.8:**

https://portablegis.xyz/post/get/

**Updating this answer with links to PortableGIS 5.6:**

I used that portable GIS (which includes QGIS) last week.  A couple of tips:

1. <strike>The whole portable system lives in directory called `usbgis` and the
   batch files expect that to live on the root of whatever drive it is
   located on. Either put it on the root, or make a junction on the
   root that points to the actual location.</strike>

   This batch file works from any directory level:
   `.\usbgis\apps\qgis2\bin\qgis-ltr.bat`
2. It is big, so make sure it
   goes on a drive with plenty of space.

<strike>It is on my to-do list to tease out a QGIS-only version of this for myself, but I haven't had time yet.  I will update this answer once I do with a link.</strike>

Or not.  The bulk of the portable package is QGIS:
[image]

Comment: Every download link in your answer is now dead (deleted by owner.) New location for Portable GIS 5.8 is here: https://portablegis.xyz/post/get/

Answer (score 4):

You can download a portable version of QGIS 2.6.1 here: http://webgis.arpa.piemonte.it/geoportale/index.php/documentazione/manuali-e-strumenti/accesso-con-qgis/100-quantum-gis-qgis

You can also create your own portable version with these instructions: http://wiki.gfoss.it/index.php/Qgis_Portable

Pages are not in English so run them through a translator if you need to.

Comment: I found these websites to be most helpful in making QGIS from OSGeo4W portable. (english)


http://www.qgis.nl/2014/04/22/qgis-in-de-klas-onder-windows/?lang=en


http://qgis.dk/arkiver/290

Answer (score 2):

There is a portable (zipped) QGIS version made by Sourcepole:

https://sourcepole.ch/produkte/interlis/

and if you want to make a portable QGIS on your own you find instructions here: https://github.com/Frederikssund/Alternativ-QGIS-installation/blob/master/Readme%20-%20english.md

I rollout portable QGIS-versions at my company based on this instructions and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

[QGIS 2.18.17.1_LTR PORTABLE, WINDOWS, 64BIT](https://allaroundgis.wordpress.com/2018/03/02/qgis-2-18-17-1-portable/)

[QGIS 3.00 PORTABLE, WINDOWS, 64BIT](https://allaroundgis.wordpress.com/2018/03/02/qgis-3-0-portable/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is still a portable version off Qgis 2.14 LTR. My experience is that it works fine. Download the portable version on desktop/laptop and from that install it on USB of 8GB.

I have had contact with the programmer and let me now that they are working on a new version. The GRASS module didn´t work was my experience.

Download link
http://archaeogeek.com/blog/2016/04/19/portablegis-5-dot-6/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most recent portable versions of QGIS, also with included GRASS from:

https://github.com/pigreco/QGIS_portable_3x